# Combobox list items not appearing

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I'm new at VBA so apologize for the elementary question.  I've looked all over to find help and have tried several different options to code but none of them seem to work for me.
I saw this post but that was the first thing I tried:
`ComboBox`, added items not showing up in list when executing code
I'm now trying this code:

```
    Private Sub UserForm1_Activate()
    Dim cName As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("PlayerListing")
    For Each cName In ws.Range("Player_Name")
    With Me.PlayerNameCombo
   .AddItem cName.Value
    End With
    Next cName
```

I want the Combobox to pull in data from a separate tab `(PlayerListing),` in a `Range (Player_Name).`
I've tried starting over, deleting everything but that doesn't seem to work either.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me as written.  Did you change the name of your userform? If you set up the Activate event when it was called Userform1, then you change the name to ufPlayerNames, the event procedure would not be properly formatted and would not be recognized as an event. Put a breakpoint somewhere in the procedure - if it stops at the break, it's OK. If not, select UserForm from the left dropdown at the top of the code pane, select Activate from the right dropdown, and cut and paste your code into the new stub.

Of maybe Player_Name isn't pointing to the range you think it is.  In the Immediate Window, type

```
?Sheets("PlayerListing").Range("Player_Name").Address
```

and make sure it's right. If, for instance, you had a bunch of blank rows at the top of Player_Name, it might look like it's not filling the combobox, but it really is filling it with a lot of blank lines.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It works now.  It was a matter of Userform1 vs. Userform.  Also, thank you for the info about the range.  That was very useful, I will use that often!  Thanks again.